# Adblock Plus マイ フィルターリスト

Tags: google-chrome

マイ フィルターリストにコメント(メモ)を付ける方法を教えてください。

Comment: cssの/* */ような方法はありませんか。

Answer (score 0):

フィルタルールの追加時、`!`で行を始めればコメント扱いになります。

[Writing Adblock Plus filters - Comments](https://adblockplus.org/en/filters#comments)